# How to change Sprite image upon collision

Tags: java, andengine

Need help on creating this, I still don't have a code yet, but my idea is to copy the original sprite, then the copied one will be put in a List that to be iterated then whenever the sprites collide I'll call the iterated copy of the sprite, anymore suggestions how to be able to change sprites image upon collision?

Comment: try http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ or http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ StackOverflow is for solving the bugs when you try to implement.

Comment: I did not got what actually you want.Explain what functionality exactly you want.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `AnimatedSprite` for collision check. When collision takes place simply change `tiledIndex` of image.